# Using the Poco C++ Library, how can I force POST to use SSL v3?

Tags: c++, openssl, 64-bit, debian, poco-libraries

I am trying to connect with SSL using the C++ Poco library. My program is able to do a POST correctly on a Debian 32 bit but it hangs when I use a 64 bit machine. I have also tried on Windows and Darwin and it works on both.

With `curl --sslv3 URI` I get a response but if I don't use v3 it hangs. Is there a way to force Poco to use SSLv3?

Comment: Any news on this? We get `(35) error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error` when **not** using `SSLV3`.